# Positioning elements inside div, inline

Tags: html, css, element

I need to position elements inside of div, here is the current div:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nZUt.jpg

this is the the desired one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXSV9.jpg

Here is the code of html and css

```css
#channel-header * {
  display: inline-block;
}

#channel-title {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="channel-header">
  <img src="images/lfc-kanal.png" id="avatar-kanala">
  <div id="channel-title">
    <h3>LFCOfficial</h3>
    <p>828,277 subscribers</p>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="sub-button">Subscribe 828K</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need for absolute. use flex. Read more about flex-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to easily create the 3 columns and have vertical alignment.

```css
#channel-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Vertical alignment */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* Horizontal alignment */
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#channel-title {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="channel-header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" id="avatar-kanala">
  <div id="channel-title">
    <h3>LFCOfficial</h3>
    <p>828,277 subscribers</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="button" id="sub-button">Subscribe 828K</a>
</div>
```